# Is it possible to install dependencies from a file in R?

Tags: r, environment, cran

In python (Anaconda), you can specify a yaml file where you put your dependencies and create an environment, like this:

```yaml
name: my_env
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - matplotlib
```

So I have two questions:

1. is there a way to load dependencies like this in R?
2. is there something like "environments" in R?

Comment: 1. In R, we have the package system. 2. Yes, there are environments in R.